# Error converting data type nvarchar to float. While copying from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

Even though my below two table are identical , I am getting below error `Error converting data type nvarchar to float.`
while copying all data from one table to other , pls help where i am missing and how to correct the same
Table 1:
[image]
Table 2:
[image]

My query to copy the data :

```
insert into [Tool Management]([Type], [Material]      ,[Material_Description]      ,[Tool_Code]      ,[Tool_Description]      ,[Tool_Life])
select [Type], [Material]      ,[Material_Description]      ,[Tool_Code]      ,[Tool_Description]      ,[Tool_Life] from sheet1$
```

Comment: Presumably you are not looking at the correct tables when you attempt to diagnose this problem - or your inserted table has a trigger. And no - the image of tables you did post clearly show your tables are not identical - just "similar".

Comment: `from sheet1$`? The source data is coming from an Excel worksheet? Excel drivers typically only look at the first few rows of a worksheet when "type guessing", so you probably want to `try_cast([Tool_Life] as float)` in your select statement. Ref: [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move information from Table 1 to Table 2, the length of the "nvarchar" columns must be equal so that no error occurs.

```
INSERT INTO table2 ([type], [Material], [Material_Description], [Tool_Code], [Tool_Description], [Tool_Life])
SELECT
CAST([type] AS NVARCHAR(20))
,[Material]
,[Material_Description]
,CAST([Tool_Code] AS NVARCHAR(20))
,[Tool_Description]
,[Tool_Life]
FROM table1
```